# How to disable auto-converting to exponential expression when using Double.parseDouble()?

Tags: java

When I run the following program:

```
System.out.println(Double.parseDouble("99999999999999") + 1);
```

I got: `1.0E14`

How can I disable the auto-conversion so that I get `100000000000000.0` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That has nothing to do with `Double.parseDouble`, and everything to do with `Double.toString`.

Try this:

```
System.out.printf("%.1f", Double.parseDouble("99999999999999") + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead.

```
    import java.math.BigDecimal;

    BigDecimal big = new BigDecimal("99999999999999");
    big = big.add(BigDecimal.ONE); // Thanks @Chris for this tip
    System.out.println(big); // Prints "100000000000000"
```

BigNumbers offer arbitrary precision. Double is limited to an (approximated) 64-bit representation. If you were to use too many 9's, you would get the wrong answer:

```
    System.out.printf("%.1f", Double.parseDouble("9999999999999998") + 1); // Note ends in 8
```

This prints `"10000000000000000.0"`, which is incorrect, should be `"9999999999999999.0"`, but the number has exceeded the accuracy of Double

Comment: Yes, it totally barks up the wrong tree. The problem isn't to do with using a double, but just the way it's formatted "by default". (I was the downvoter, for the record.) Plus, you should be shot for using `new BigDecimal(1)` when `BigDecimal.ONE` is a much better choice. :-)

Comment: BigDecimal might be overkill in this case, but the OP does appear to be trying to use crazy precision as well, so it might be the right way to go.

Comment: I've retracted my downvote, because you've provided a suitable use case for BigDecimal, namely when you overflow what a double allows. Granted, different from the OP's question, but still of value.